# Match select text between delimiter

Tags: php, regex

For some reason my regex is matching what I am after and extra. I am needing to just match the `group #`, but it's matching the first number of the phone numbers also.

Example data:

```
id: N group: 1 category: NAMES : Mike
id: N group: 2 category: NAMES : Seth
id: # group: 1 category: PHONE : 123-456-789
id: # group: 2 category: PHONE : 111 111-1111
id: @ group: 1 category: EMAIL : mike@mail.com
id: @ group: 2 category: EMAIL : seth@yahoo.com
```

Regex

```
preg_match_all('/:\s+\d/', $data, $matches);
```

Current output

```
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
2
```

Expected output

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

Comment: if the position does not change you could simply uses substr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a lookahead, to make sure that `category` follows immediately:

```
preg_match_all('/:\s+\d(?= category)/', $data, $matches);
```

The lookahead is not captured, but strings won't match if it isn't there.

Comment: You must match the integer after 'group:'

Comment: @UlrichHorus Did you think before you made that comment and downvote? I'm matching the number that comes before `category`, which amounts to precisely the same thing, given the data.

Comment: What about the integer after phone: and email:?

Comment: @UlrichHorus I don't know, what about them?

Comment: That exactly what i was thinking about

Comment: @UlrichHorus You know, it's quite rude to give a downvote on a correct answer (which this is, by the way) and not explain why.

Comment: So i vote you all up. I ve seen the category now. But i m not sure if hwnd s answer every time work

Comment: It works in a way that excludes the whitespace and gives the exact match.

Answer (score 3):

Change your regular expression through

```
"/group:\s*(\d+)/i"
```

The issue is that you have also  ":" after PHONE and EMAIL

Comment: The other answers do work, but I think this one is the best.  The capturing group makes it easy to extract just the number, and it's both simpler and more flexible than the lookaround approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following, which will also *exclude* the whitespace and give you your exact match.

```
preg_match_all('/(?<![^ ])\d(?!\d)/', $data, $matches);
```

See [`live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/mO1lU7)

Or to be safe, you could just use a look ahead.

```
preg_match_all('/\d(?= +category)/i', $data, $matches);
```

See [`live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/aA2eD0)

Better yet, just simply match for `group:` and the following number.

```
preg_match_all('/group:\s+\K\d/i', $data, $matches);
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? This works [See here](http://regex101.com/r/jB0yA4)

Comment: You must match the integer after 'group:'

Comment: It is matching the number after group!

Comment: And after phone an email?

Comment: If you look at both links I provided examples you will see that it is matching the group number, I would rethink before you start downvoting answers.

Comment: He say 'needing to just match the group #,'

Comment: Again, it matches the group number just as he says he wants his output to be.

Comment: @Ulrich horus sorry but he is right and this matches what i want